# Vuejs - setting the value of a textbox. (in laravel)

Tags: forms, models, vue.js

I am trying to set the value of a textbox with vuejs

@{{ message }} works in the body or in a

tag.

this does not

```
<input type="text" name="column_name" v-model="reverseMessage" value="{{message}}">
```

Neither does.

```
   <input type="text" name="column_name" v-model="reverseMessage" value="@{{message}}">
```

Comment: Which vuejs version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to bind input value **multiple variables**. Both to `reverseMessage` (using v-model) and to `value` (using interpolation).

Please remove `value="{{message}}"` and just set `reverseMessage` variable - this should update the input view.

```
<input type="text" name="column_name" v-model="reverseMessage"/>
```

and then

```
this.reverseMessage = "my new input value"
```

You cannot bind input to many variables in the template itself. Use watchers or computed properties if you really need this.